# Is the following statement true about generating set of a group?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ be a group. Let $X$ be a subset of $G$ and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then is the following statement true?
Suppose that $$G=\langle X, H\rangle.$$
Can we write $$G=\langle X\rangle H?$$ where the above product is internal product of subgroups.

My Attempt: if $H$ is trivial subgroup, then above statement is true. For non-trivial subgroup, it seems to me that it is correct. But unable to have a proof of the same. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not true in general.

Consider $G=\mathbb{F}_2$ the free group on two generators $a,b\in\mathbb{F}_2$. Then let $X=\{a\}$ and $H=\langle b\rangle$. Note that clearly $G=\langle X,H\rangle$, but it is not true that $G=\langle X\rangle H$, because the set on the right is of the form $\{a^nb^m\}$, and it does not contain for example $ba$.

**EDIT:** Note that the statement is true when at least one of $H$, $\langle X\rangle$ is normal. More generally, given two subgroups $H$, $K$ if one of them is normal, then $HK=KH$. And this implies that $\langle H,K\rangle=HK$.

Comment: If we, in particular, take H=G′, then is is true?

Comment: Yes, it is true. Because the commutator subgroup is normal. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is an overkill, but I'd like to provide the next example.

It is known that a group generated by $2$ involutions is dihedral. If your statement is true, then $|G|=|\langle X\rangle H|=\dfrac{|\langle X\rangle||H|}{|\langle X\rangle \cap H|}=|\langle X\rangle||H|=4$, for every dihedral group $G$, which is not a case, of course.

It is worth to note that it is true, when $H$ is the Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G)$, that can be characterized as the set of all **non-generating** elements.